# Did Young Sheldon leave Wilmot Academy just because of the first living arrangement?

Tags: the-big-bang-theory, young-sheldon

S01E10 of Young Sheldon:

> Flora, I have to ask about the living arrangements. That's our main concern.
>
> Well, I think I can reassure you about that. My husband and I have been hosting a student for the last several years who recently graduated and is now at Princeton. So we have a guest room available in our home.

I don't see why they didn't try to get different arrangements, either before or after the first day of living with the principal. There may be some assumed understanding that other arrangements are limited or expensive for them or something I missed earlier about how other arrangements violate other conditions (eg no dog).

Comment: It's a sitcom. Also, episodes are short (< 20 minutes) so there isn't much time to explore more story in one episode. And the point isn't about the living arrangements (including the string beans etc.), but about how Sheldon is loved by his family and how he himself is also missing them. Note that it's his father who "breaks" and who goes to get him back, despite him being in favor of Sheldon leaving.

Comment: @BCdotWEB 1. What does love have to do with leaving/not leaving? 2. I thought the point was that Sheldon's missing his family wouldn't get in the way of moving to another school and that that was not a reason for his not wanting to attend. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 4):

Point is: Neither Sheldon nor his family was able to live without each other. Even Missy was so bothered with his absence. Issue was not the principle's house or their folk rock-singing but the issue was the pain of leaving far from family.

In the start we got to know that Sheldon's family can't afford to live near to that new school due to the money. So after realizing they can't live apart, no point in searching more arrangements.